Header and footer of a Fluent-ui Panel are not sticky
I am working on a React web app. I created an icon picker that is displayed in a Fluent-Ui panel. This icon picker works very well. We have been using it for many months. But... I recently updated many modules, like FluentUi and React and since then, the panel header and footer are not sticky anymore. I guess something has changed in Fluent-Ui... Can someone guides me on what I should do to resolve this issue? Thanks a lot in advance!
Here is the icon picker:
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactIcons from "@fluentui/react-icons-mdl2";
import { PrimaryButton } from "@fluentui/react/lib/Button";
import { Icon, Panel, PanelType, Separator, Stack, TextField, initializeIcons } from "@fluentui/react";
import styles from "./RqIconPicker.module.scss";
import { CommonButton } from "../CommonButton";

interface IRqIconPickerProps {
    closePanelCallback: (selectedIconName: string) => void;
}

const icons = Object.keys(ReactIcons).reduce((acc: React.FC[], exportName) => {
    //eslint-disable-next-line
    if ((ReactIcons as any)[exportName]?.displayName) {
        //eslint-disable-next-line
        acc.push((ReactIcons as any)[exportName] as React.FunctionComponent);
    }

    return acc;
}, []);

initializeIcons();

export const RqIconPicker: React.FunctionComponent<IRqIconPickerProps> = ({ closePanelCallback }) => {
    const [numOfPages, setNumOfPages] = React.useState<number>(0);
    const [page, setPage] = React.useState<number>(1);
    const [selectedIcon, setSelectedIcon] = React.useState<string>("");
    const [iconFilter, setIconFilter] = React.useState<string>("");
    const [displayedIcons, setDisplayedIcons] = React.useState<React.FC[]>([]);

    const isSearchFilterTarget = (iconName?: string): boolean => {
        return iconName?.toLowerCase().indexOf(iconFilter.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const filteredIcons: React.FC[] = icons
            .filter((i: React.FunctionComponent<ReactIcons.ISvgIconProps>) => isSearchFilterTarget(i.displayName));

        setNumOfPages(parseInt((filteredIcons.length / 100).toString(), 10) + (filteredIcons.length % 100 > 0 ? 1 : 0));
        setDisplayedIcons(filteredIcons.slice((page - 1) * 100, (page - 1) * 100 + 100));

        if (filteredIcons.length === 0) {
            setPage(0);
        }
        else if (page === 0) {
            setPage(1);
        }
    }, [iconFilter, page]);

    const goToNextPage = (): void => {
        setPage(page + 1);
    }

    const goToPrevPage = (): void => {
        setPage(page - 1);
    };

    const onChangeIconFilter = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>, newValue?: string): void => {
        const filterValue: string = newValue ? newValue : "";

        setIconFilter(filterValue);

        if (filterValue.trim().length <= 1) {
            setPage(1);
        }
    }

    const onRenderHeaderContent = React.useCallback(
        () => (
            <div>
                <div className={styles.headerTextDiv}>
                    <span>
                        Sélectionner une icône
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.navigationButtonsDiv}>
                    <PrimaryButton
                        // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-bind
                        onClick={goToPrevPage}
                        disabled={page === 1 || numOfPages === 0}
                        className={styles.navigationButton}
                    >
                        Précédent
                    </PrimaryButton>
                    <PrimaryButton
                        // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-bind
                        onClick={goToNextPage}
                        disabled={page === numOfPages || numOfPages === 0}
                        className={styles.navigationButton}
                    >
                        Suivant
                    </PrimaryButton>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.navigationTextDiv}>
                    <span className={styles.navigationTextSpan}>
                        Page {page} de {numOfPages}
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <TextField className={styles.searchFilterTextField} onChange={onChangeIconFilter} placeholder="Veuillez saisir le nom d'une icône" />
                </div>
                <Separator />
            </div>
        ),
        [page, numOfPages]
    );

    const onRenderFooterContent = React.useCallback(
        () => (
            <div className={styles.footer}>
                <Stack horizontal disableShrink>
                    <CommonButton
                        buttonId="btnValider"
                        buttonText="Enregistrer"
                        iconName="Save"
                        typeSubmit={true}
                        dataTestId="btnSaveIconPicker"
                        clickCallback={() => { closePanelCallback(selectedIcon) }}
                        disabled={!selectedIcon}
                    />
                    <CommonButton
                        buttonId="btnAnnuler"
                        buttonText="Annuler"
                        iconName="Cancel"
                        dataTestId="btnCancelIconPicker"
                        clickCallback={() => { closePanelCallback("") }}
                    />
                </Stack>
            </div>
        ),
        [closePanelCallback, selectedIcon]
    );

    return (
        <div>
            <Panel
                isOpen={true}
                closeButtonAriaLabel="Close"
                hasCloseButton={false}
                onRenderHeader={onRenderHeaderContent}
                onRenderFooterContent={onRenderFooterContent}
                type={PanelType.medium}
                isFooterAtBottom={true}
            >
                <div>
                    {displayedIcons
                        .map((fluentUIIcon: React.FunctionComponent<ReactIcons.ISvgIconProps>, index) => (
                            <div key={index}
                                className={`${styles.cell} ${selectedIcon === fluentUIIcon.displayName ? styles.selected : ""}`}
                                onClick={() => setSelectedIcon(fluentUIIcon.displayName ? fluentUIIcon.displayName : "")}
                            >
                                <Icon aria-label={fluentUIIcon.displayName?.replace("Icon", "")}
                                    className={`${styles.icon} ${selectedIcon === fluentUIIcon.displayName ? styles.iconSelected : ""}`}
                                    iconName={fluentUIIcon.displayName?.replace("Icon", "")}
                                />
                                <code className={`${styles.code} ${selectedIcon === fluentUIIcon.displayName ? styles.codeSelected : ""}`}>
                                    {fluentUIIcon.displayName}
                                </code>
                            </div>
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
            </Panel>
        </div>
    );
};

